# Text vs. audio representations of words

Tags: linguistics

**"Word"**
This can refer to at least three things:

1. A textual representation of a *_*
2. A sonic representation of *_*
3. *_* , the superconcept containing 1 & 2.

What are specific...words for each of these concepts?

Comment: What is wrong with **word**? It seems to fit all three blanks in the question...

Comment: Written word vs spoken word vs word.

Comment: Let me point one deficiency of your examples: if we imagine that there are two distinct terms A and B that fit under __ for 1 and 2, respectively, you have still failed to describe the difference between them (because it is completely acceptable that A=B, and still that its textual and sonic representations are a different sense of the term word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A word as it appears on the page is an *orthographic word.* Each separate occurrence of an orthographic word is a *token*. So, in the sentence ‘The cat sat on the mat’ there are six tokens. If we don’t want to count ‘the’ twice, we say there are five *types*. Words that share the same basic meaning are *lexemes*. They are the words we look up in a dictionary. Thus, *walks, walking* and *walked* are three orthographic words, but they represent only one lexeme. The smallest unit of meaning is a *morpheme*. *Walk* is a morpheme all on its own, but *walks, walking* and *walked* are each made up of two morphemes, *walk* and the inflectional endings *-s*, *-ing* and *-ed*.

There is no special term for a spoken word. *Phoneme*, however, describes the smallest unit of sound that can indicate a change in meaning. In the word *pit* there are three phonemes, /p/, /ɪ/ and /t/. We can change each of these in turn and produce three different words, ‘bit’, ‘pat’ and ‘pin’.

There is no term other than *word* to describe both written and spoken manifestations of the smallest unit of grammar that can stand on its own as a complete utterance.

Comment: Utterance is listed as "a word or phrase that someone speaks" in macmillan, with a tag *linguistics*; though it does extend to phrases. +1

Comment: @Unreason: The characteristic of an utterance is its lack of grammatical structure and that is indeed more typical of spoken than of written language. I should perhaps have said that I have borrowed the wording in my last paragraph from David Crystal’s ‘Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’.

Answer (score 1):

Is the distinction you are looking for:

**oral**: spoken

**verbal**: subsumes oral *and* includes written text

[Note: my source here is Bill Bryson's *Dictionary of Troublesome Words*. I am aware that a few experts have pointed out errors in *DTW* much as Bryson pointed out  the numerous errors in the experts' published work.

Comment: No, I am specifically referring to the representations of a concept, within the context of linguistics I guess. Those two terms describe properties of the words I'm looking for but are not those words themselves. The specific words would be the oral representation, the textual representation, and the verbal superconcept.

Answer (score 0):

Written word vs spoken word (or utterance) vs meaning

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're thinking of "morpheme," the written expression of a lexeme, and "phoneme," it's audible form.

Technically, both morphemes and phonemes refer to subdivided, irreducible lexical units, however in the extended sense they can be used to refer to words in general, per your question.